# React - Get paginated data from context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have the current context

```
export function UserPostsProvider({ children }) {
  const [posts, dispatch] = useReducer(userPostsReducer, initialState);

  const addUserPosts = (userId, posts, unshift = false) => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.addUserPosts(userId, posts, unshift));
  };

  const getUserPosts = (userId, index = 0, limit = undefined) => {
    const _posts = posts[userId] ?? [];
    return _posts.slice(index, limit + index || undefined);
  };

  return (
    <UserPostsContext.Provider
      value={{
        addUserPosts,
        deleteUserPost,
        getUserPosts,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserPostsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I have a method "getUserPosts" which accepts two arguments "index" and "limit".

I am consuming this context as follows:

```
export default function useFetchUserPosts(userData) {
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();

  const userPosts = useUserPosts();

  const cards = useCards();

  const posts = userPosts.getUserPosts(userData.id); // <--- HERE!
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(!posts.length);
  const [error, serError] = useState(undefined);

  const startAfter = useRef(new Date()); 

  const getMorePosts = async (limit = 10) => {
     if (isFetching.current || !hasMoreToLoad.current || !isMounted()) {
           return;
     }

     isFetching.current = true;

     setIsLoading(true);

     try {
        const {
           posts: newPosts,
           hasMoreToLoad: newHasMoreToLoad,
           startAfter: newStartAfter,
        } = await getUserPosts(userData.id, startAfter.current, limit);

        // The component might be unmounted
        if (!isMounted()) return;

        hasMoreToLoad.current = newHasMoreToLoad;

        startAfter.current = newStartAfter;

        userPosts.addUserPosts(userData.id, newPosts);

        setIsLoading(false);

        isFetching.current = false;
     } catch(err) {
       setError(err);
     }         
  }
  
  ...
}
```

How can I do  to get the correct a paginated section of the posts from the context? I mean, if I just get the  first 10 posts  from the context on each re-render, I will be always getting the first 10 posts, no more than that.

Any helps?

Comment: I need to accumulate previous posts too inside the hook, and only get the necessary data (pagination).

Comment: Does the API you are consuming support paginated data? Or you only have `_posts` to paginate over?

Comment: @MhdLouayAl-osh yeah, it supports paginated data, I can send it the cursors and limits